# rotation precision of known object

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to use OpenCV to find a QR-Code in an image and to get the rotation angle of it. How to find the object is shown in the `Features2D + Homography to find a known object` example of the OpenCV collection.
What I'm interested in is how I can estimate the precision of the rotation angle and what would be the most accurate method.

Btw. camera calibration is done.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a long paragraph on analytical estimation of scientific errors, but even if it's the most accurate method, it's a lost cause unless you have a lot of time on your hands and are set to fly to Mars. An analytical approach is hard work (but certainly not impossible).

A more realistic way is to just estimate the error statistically. Vary some parameters by mutating the image (scaling, rotation, etc), make a fit of the expected vs observed angle, see how they rely on the size of contour, min height or min width, eccentricity, etc. Choose some factors, see what power they have, then hope that they fit well into some visible formula like angle_deviation = a1*x^n1 * a2*y^n2 * a3*z^n3 (e.g. 1.234*width^2 * 1.111*height^2 * 2.8*area).

[This will be useful.](http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html)

Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, I expected this as straight forward at least in the case of a single line...